# Purpose of this Resistor in Circuit attached

Tags: operational-amplifier

What is the purpose of resistor (R2, 33ohm) in the circuit below?

Q) is it for current limiting , if So the current can go 15V/33ohm = 454mA, but opamp can not give this much current , most opamp can give only some 20-50mA only, so this resistor needed

Q) or it is used for termination , if so how they calculate its value.

[image]

Comment: Could be for capacitive load isolation.  Without knowing exactly what the load looks like it's hard to say.

Comment: Never, ever, ever, post a schematic with this colour scheme again, ever. If you use the built in schematic editor people can actually read it.

Comment: @Asmyldof I totally agree - its horrible. I've edited the abomination.

Answer (score 3):

R2 is often on opamp outouts .Like John D commented it provides some capacitive load isolation .It also isolates RF and is sometimes referred to as a "Stopper resistor".For termimation you assume that the opamp has zero output impedence so in your example the circuit has an output impedance of 33R .The resistor does not waste much output voltage and can allow for easy trouble free paralleling of opamps in order to get more current .Real loads have inductance and capacitance which can not always be ignored .You can get ringing if there is a highish Q .The series resistor reduces the Q and hence the ringing .I have heard the term "Damping resistor" used in the old days.